# How to read time in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible in  javascript to read time?

For instance, if there is countdown clock for 30 minutes, is there a way for my program to read the timer when there is 10 minutes left and prompt user.

I have used this example from stack overflow:

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
```

```html
<body>
    <div>Registration closes in <span id="time">05:00</span> minutes!</div>
</body>
```

Comment: So start adding if statements.....

Comment: And setTimeout is not accurate

Comment: You can do everything with javascript. However its unclear what you want to do.

Comment: `new Date()` will return the current time. You can compare this to the completion time to test when there are 10 minutes left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add a global variable to check if you show the alarm or not just check the `minutes` and do what every you like.

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
        
        // Have Fun Here
        if(minutes < 10)display.style = "color:red";


        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    var TheMinutes = 60 * 11,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(TheMinutes, display);
};
```

```html
<body>
    <div>Registration closes in <span id="time">11:00</span> minutes!</div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is super inefficient

Comment: This is just an example for this case not for producing and it is based on the example that we received that is all.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reading the "Timer" I would recommend setting two timeouts, this would require less processing

**Example**

```
//Using seconds instead of minutes
cons second = 1000;
setTimeout(function(){ alert("10 seconds left"); }, 10 * second);
setTimeout(function(){ alert("30 seconds is up"); }, 30 * second);
```

Comment: Actually this would not be accurate, the delay passed as an argument is the lower bound, it could be 11s or 12 or 20 depending on how things turn out (heavy operations, etc...)

Comment: Actually this would be accurate within 1 ms unless someone was on a computer from the 90s.setTimeout is a super fast operation and the function it calls is not run until the end of  timeout

Answer (score 0):

Just add an if statement, this one will stop at 10:30 left. Just change the numbers.

Put this inside the interval.

```
 if(minutes == 10 && seconds == 30){
      alert("there is ten minutes and thirty seconds left") 
 }
```